# Issue with Mobile Bootstrap menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't get the Mobile version of the menu right... Here are some screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/keTvn.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBzi0.jpg

using Bootstrap JS and CSS

EDIT:
Sorry for not asking any question. My question is when i open it mobile i wont see the collapse menu button and when i open is in a small browser i do... can anybody help me with this?

```css
body {
    background-color: #adadad;
}

.log{
    background-color: #C7002B;
    height: 40px;
}
.logblock{
    /*width: 1080px;*/
    margin: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.logtext{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 32px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.logtext a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar{
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-toggle{
    margin-top: 23px;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar-brand img {
    height: 50px;
}
.navbar-nav li a{
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: -2px;
}



.dropdown-menu li a{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
/*@media (min-width: 768px){
    .logblock {
        width: 1080px;
    }
    .container-fluid{
        width: 1080px;
    }

}*/

@media (max-width: 768px){
    .logblock{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar-header{
        height: 75px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-color: #e7e7e7;
    }
    .navbar-nav li a{
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .container-fluid{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question and what types of question are on topic for the site

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and here [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you know the OPs code? They haven't provided any.